# Simple javascript regular expression - add another keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I update this regular expression to find and replace not just "/news/" but "/blog/" as well?

```
urlLinks = $(this).attr("href").replace(/(\/news\/)/, "$1article/");
```

It's a simple one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
urlLinks = $(this).attr("href").replace(/(\/(news|blog)\/)/, "$1article/");
```

Tested like so:

```
>>> 'http://www.example.org/news/test.html'.replace(/(\/(news|blog)\/)/, "$1article/");
"http://www.example.org/news/article/test.html"
>>> 'http://www.example.org/blog/test.html'.replace(/(\/(news|blog)\/)/, "$1article/");
"http://www.example.org/blog/article/test.html"
```